# Details of TOCFL online?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there an online description of Test Of Chinese as a Foreign Language (TOCFL) in Spanish or English that's better than [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_of_Chinese_as_a_Foreign_Language)?

Both Wikipedia and the [official site](https://www.sc-top.org.tw/english/eng_index.php) say that the final level adds no new words to the previous levels.  Wikipedia has two tables that disagree on the numbers of words in each level, and another site has a third set of numbers.  The official site agrees with the first Wikipedia table.  But the official site also has two word lists for what appears to be pre-test levels.  I'd like to know more about them.  That site's levels:

```
準備一級  Pre 1    145 words
準備二級  Pre 2    171 words added
入門級    Lev 1    186 words added
基礎級    Lev 2    496 words added
進階級    Lev 3   1481 words added
高階級    Lev 4   2490 words added
流利級    Lev 5   2986 words added
```

Comment: And level five's name appears to be "fluency" which makes me wonder what level six is!

Answer (score -1):

I think the details in [2018TOCFL_guidelines](https://www.sc-top.org.tw/download/2018TOCFL_guidelines(20180208).pdf), on page 14(or pdf file page 18) is what you are looking for.